# How to rewrite URL using .htaccess in Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, joomla2.5

How to rewrite given URL /component/com_m2c/Itemid,667/view,m2c/ to gallery for Joomla?!

I was trying to put in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^component/com_m2c/Itemid,667/view,m2c galerry [NC,L]
```

nothing happens;
but if I put full URL like

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^component/com_m2c/Itemid,667/view,m2c http://example.com/galerry [NC,L]
```

It just Redirects me to given URL , but there is No Content.....

I need the URL to be 
    /gallery 
and to show there content of 
    component/com_m2c/Itemid,667/view,m2c

Comment: If redirected to `http://example.com/galerry`, for example, with the URL-path appended it becomes `http://example.com/galerry/component/com_m2c/Itemid,667/view,m2c/`, is that what you want?

Comment: Is there no "alias" property for this component. If you find one, that should allow you to use `/gallery` in your URL route.

Comment: it becomes http://example.com/galerry/component/com_m2c/Itemid,667/view,m2c/, is that what you want? (C) - No way, all I need is /galerry not all the rest junk.....

Answer (score 0):

You should not be creating a rewrite for this.

To utilise SEF URLs in Joomla you need to create a menu item that points to that view in that component - the menu item will need to be a level 1 menu item with the alias "gallery".

You can only create a menu item for that component, if the component defines menu item types for it.

Comment: alias doesn't work , it's an external component to create a blank component, there are no alias and placing it in menu doesn't help. The Menu item tells "Gallery" and alias is gallery, but the link is still component/com_m2c/Itemid,667/view,m2c